game launchers not working
Recently swapped to ubuntu and while most linux compatible games work perfectly, anything using a custom or proprietary launcher refuses to start. For example; When you launch Cyberpunk2077 through steam it starts a launcher for cp2077 through which you then launch the game. This launcher will not start for cp2077 or any other game i've tried that uses its own personal launcher.
For further clarification:

I start the game
The game attempts to run for a few seconds, usually with steam telling me that it is running, although nothing shows up(as far as i can tell) even in the system monitor
Steam(presumably) realises nothing it running or booting and removes the running/starting icon from the game

Also, Sorry if this is complete nonsense, all i know about computers is click button to play game:(

Welcome to the world of tweaking Steam to run your games.
I also run Steam on Ubuntu 24.04.
While some games work others require some non-obvious steps to sidestep problems.
My first step when a game will not run is to try changing the compatibility framework.  That is a WINE layer used by Steam to run Windows apps.
In the Steam settings Compatibility screen try choosing Proton Experimental or some other version for "Run other titles with".

If that does not work, look at the comments for your game at ProtonDB.  These are folks who managed to get it to work using various levels of tinkering.Start looking at the most recent suggestion that matches your installation (Ubuntu by OP).
https://www.protondb.com/app/1091500
Here is a static screenshot showing that user Jimbo had good results switching to Proton Experimental.

The suggestions change frequently with newer linux distributions and kernels so be sure to check out the link.


Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It would be great if you could additionally summarize the suggestions from the linked site in your answer, as links can stop working which would make your post less valuable. Ideally every answer should be able to stand on its own and only include links for further reference.

I added a screenshot of the specific game tweak suggestions.  However, my answer is about how to find the help they need.  Not for what to do for a specific game.
OP even says "for example".
Additionally, summarizing tweaking details for a specific game will very quickly become out of date.  Such misleading info is a liability in an answer IMO.
